# Undefined Control Sequence with imakeidx

Tags: errors, indexing, imakeidx

I am using `imakeidx` to make multiple indices for my report, but I ran into a problem where I get an "Undefined Control Sequence" error when I try to compile. The problem is shown below.
[image: Undefined Control Sequence Error]

When I open the specified `.ind` file, I see this.
[image: IND File Contents]

Considering I've never had to worry about `.ind` files before, I did not modify this file. The code that produces that index entry is here.
[image: TEX File Contents]

I'm not quite sure what is wrong with this declaration, since I've never had problems with `imakeidx` before.

Comment: The undefined control sequence is `\AT` which I never heard about.

Comment: in all the other cases you have `\ AT` ie a control-space followed by AT, that one you have `\AT` which is an undefined command

Comment: although since it is `imakeidx` package we should blame @egreg.

Comment: Looking again at the `\index` item in the LaTeX, I specify `\index{P00-F120DG-AA | AT-101-042}`, so I'm not sure how that turns into `\item P00-F120DG-AA , \hyperindexformat{\AT-101-042}{29}`. In fact, looking at a test file I made, the IND line should be: `\item P00-F120DG, \ AT-101-042{29}`.

I'm confused why `imakeidx` is formatting is strangely.

Comment: the `|` symbol has a special meaning in any `*makeidx` context -- it is the substitute for a backslash to control commands like `\see`.  instead of a literal `|`, substitute `\vert\ ` (there is a space at the end). and it might be helpful to check some documentation for `makeidx` or `imakeidx`.  there is an example of the use of `|` in the latter documentation, in section 5.2.5: `{...{#1|innote}}`.  (there are probably better references, but i haven't time to look just now.)

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton! I thought I had check the documentation, but I guess I missed that... You should also post that as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 4):

the problem here is the presence of a `|` in a string that is being written into
an `\index` entry.

the `|` has a special function in index entries: it substitutes for (and is
interpreted as) a backslash for commands that are relevant to the indexing
process, such as `\see` (input as `|see` in `\index{...}`) or the "brackets"
that indicate a page span, `|(` and `|)`.

the proper way to input this character in an index entry depends on whether it
is in math or text.

in text, a `|` can be "quoted" by preceding it with a ditto mark: `"|`.

in math, the proper substitution is `\vert`, or, if the
string to appear in the index output is `||`, then `\Vert`.  since these are
often paired, `\lvert ... \rvert` or `\abs{...}` (or the equivalents for the
double forms) are often more appropriate.

Comment: Preceding the pipe symbol with a ditto mark did not prevent the error from occurring. It was still interpreted as a control symbol rather than a pipe.

Comment: @HariGanti -- what is the exact entry in the `.idx` file that is failing?  and what does it become in the `.ind` file?

Answer (score 0):

Barbara Beeton pointed out (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326635/220244) that  `|`  has a special function in index entries, which causes the problem.

This problem occurs, for example, if

```
\index(maintopic!subtopic)
```

was accidentally misspelled to

```
\index(maintopic|subtopic)
```

Comment: Hey @Matthias, would you mind also describing the points from Barbaras comment, so they are combined in this answer? Without this explicit context, it is a bit hard to understand and I think your answer would benefit.